# Facebook login issue in Swift and iOS9

Tags: swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have been trying to create a Tinder clone app. Right now I have to login to my Facebook account, grab my profile and show my display picture.

I have imported the latest FBSDK, confirgured my plist ([Plist screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xae1I.jpg)) correctly and used the graphRequest function to pull my profile picture but I keep getting the following error.

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

I have cleaned my build, restarted my simulator, restarted my machine and completely commented out my parse code.

I have uncommented all my parse code (which I am deploying through Heroku) so as not to simplify the code.

I have Googled the problem and searched stack overflow and github for over 2 weeks and have yet to find a solution.

I have read comments about how this problem is a red herring due to Facebooks SDK integration with iOS 9.

I want to know what I am doing wrong. I am new to coding and need some help. All I want to achieve right now is to login to my Facebook account (which I can do), authorise my app (which I can also do) and see my profile picture in the UiImageView (which I can NOT do). This way I can keep building the app along with my course.

```
    /**
* Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
* All rights reserved.
*
* This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
* LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
* of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
*/

//current project 02-04-16

import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4


// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// import ParseUI

// deleted parseFacebookUtils and added ParseFacebookUtilsV4 so that PFFacebookUtils.intializeFacebookWithLaunchOptions would work. Replace parseFacebookUtils if needed to go back to old code (19-04-16).

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
    //--------------------------------------



    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.

//        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
//        
//        let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
//            
//            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "tinder9121hughglass1234"
//            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "sam123456hibabina"
//            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://tinder-sam2.herokuapp.com//parse"


            PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)



//            Uncomment these lines if you want to enable Parse 
//            PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
//            
//
//            PFUser.logOut()

//            let defaultACL = PFACL();


            //this is the current project 23-03-16


//            PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
//            Parse.setApplicationId("tinder9121hughglass1234", clientKey: "sam123456hibabina")



            //this code has been // temporarily 05-04-16 ***

//            
//            let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
//            fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], handler: { (result, error) in
//            
//                
//            })
//            
//            PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
//            
//            

//        })

//          edited again here!
//        let PFObject = PFUser.currentUser()
//
//        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
//
//        let acl = PFACL()
//        acl.publicReadAccess = true
//        acl.publicWriteAccess = true
//        PFObject?.ACL = acl

//        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
//        defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true

//        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var noPushPayload = false;
            if let options = launchOptions {
                noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }

        //
        //  Swift 1.2
        //
        //        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        //            let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        //            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        //            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //        } else {
        //            let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        //        }

        //
        //  Swift 2.0
        //
        //        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        //            let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        //            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
        //            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //        } else {
        //            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        //            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        //        }

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Push Notifications
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            if succeeded {
                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
            } else {
                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
            }
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Uncomment this method if you want to use Push Notifications with Background App Refresh
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //     if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
    //         PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    //     }
    // }

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: Facebook SDK Integration
    //--------------------------------------

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Uncomment this method if you are using Facebook
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    //     return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, session:PFFacebookUtils.session())
    // }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()   
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this line into your `Info.plist`: `<string>fbauth2</string>`

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: Thankyou that worked to stop the error message. Now to get the app to show my profile picture. Thanks!